# On Screen keyboard - Windows 8.1 Tablet

Tags: c#, windows, windows-8.1

we've been working on an application for the past 5 years, and we're just now getting to where we want the program to run on the surface pro 3, the main problem we're running into is the on-screen keyboard does not open when a textbox is clicked.

i am trying to find a way, to bind an application wide event that would open the keyboard anytime a textbox is touched, is this possible, or do we need to go through the entire application and fire the keyboard manually anytime we think we'll need it?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the keyboard won't open when a textbox is clicked or touched unless it's in a WindowsStoreApplication

Comment: I'm looking for the answer to this myself, but this appears to be incorrect because Google Chrome shows the keyboard when text entry is required.  It is a desktop app.

Answer (score 0):

I Created a keyboard function and found this answer somewhere else on here about 2 months ago. If i can find it again I will update this with the link. I am using a Surface 2 pro tablet and the code is:

```
 class KeyboardFunction
{
    //Used for close keyboard method
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

    public const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112;
    public const int SC_CLOSE = 0xF060;
    //End close keyboard inputs


    /*
   *Opens the tablet keyboard on device
   *
   */
    public void openKeyboardOnTablet()
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\TabTip.exe");

    }

    /*
  *Close on screen keyboard
  *
  */
    public void closeOnscreenKeyboard()
    {
        // retrieve the handler of the window  
        int iHandle = FindWindow("IPTIP_Main_Window", "");
        if (iHandle > 0)
        {
            // close the window using API        
            SendMessage(iHandle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, SC_CLOSE, 0);
        }
    }

}
```

As far as I am aware there is no way to tell the surface to open up the keyboard with only numbers. This just opens the default keyboard. I have tried to include the surface dll but that did nothing in my c# desktop application. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it in Windows 8.1 with WPF, and this code can be used in Windows 10 as well except that you may have to make modifications to work better with the new `Touch Panel and Handwriting Service`:

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Interactivity;
using System.Windows.Threading;

    public class KeyboardFocusBehavior : Behavior<Control>
    {
        public bool Focused
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(FocusedProperty); }
            set { SetValue(FocusedProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty FocusedProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Focused", 
            typeof(bool), 
            typeof(ControlKeyboardFocusBehavior), 
            new PropertyMetadata(false, OnFocusedPropertyChanged));

        private static void OnFocusedPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            ControlKeyboardFocusBehavior b = d as ControlKeyboardFocusBehavior;

            if(b != null && b.AssociatedObject != null)
            {
                Control c = b.AssociatedObject;

                if (!c.IsFocused && (bool)e.NewValue)
                {
                    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Input, new Action(delegate()
                    {
                        c.Focus();         
                        Keyboard.Focus(c);
                        TouchKeyboard.Show();
                    }));
                }
            }
        }

    public class ShowTouchKeyboardOnFocusBehavior : Behavior<Control>
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();
            WeakEventManager<Control, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs>.AddHandler(AssociatedObject, "GotKeyboardFocus", OnGotKeyboardFocus);
            WeakEventManager<Control, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs>.AddHandler(AssociatedObject, "LostKeyboardFocus", OnLostKeyboardFocus);
        }

        private void OnGotKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // show the touch keyboard
            TouchKeyboard.Show();
            var textBox = sender as TextBox;
            if (textBox != null)
                textBox.SelectionStart = Math.Max(0, textBox.Text.Length);
        }

        private void OnLostKeyboardFocus(object sender, KeyboardFocusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // hide the touch keyboard
            TouchKeyboard.Hide();
        }
    }
```

Then in the WPF XAML file, for a given textbox:

```
                        <Border  CornerRadius="0,5,5,0" Style="{StaticResource TextBoxBorder}" >
                            <TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextBoxInput}" Text="{Binding MyTextProperty}" >
                                <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                    <behaviors:ShowTouchKeyboardOnFocusBehavior />
                                </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            </TextBox>
                        </Border>
```